# Multilevel model by two step estimation

Tags: multilevel-analysis

Consider the simple multilevel model
$$
\begin{align}
Y_{ij} &= X_{ij} B + u_{ij}, \\
B &= Z_{j}R + e_{j}. \\
\end{align}
$$

What happens if firstly the parameters vector $B$ is
estimated by linear regression (OLS), then secondly the OLS estimate vector 
is regressed on $Z_{j}$ (instead of REML)?

Any suggestion of reference (article or textbook) would be very helpful.